# NHibernate intersection

Tags: nhibernate, intersection

How can i do intersection in nhibernate?
is

```
select enterprise.Id 
from Enterprises

intersect

select enterpiseID 
from vEnterprise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A21
>
> It doesn't currently support union or
>   intersect.

_

> You could use a named sql-query and do
>   the union in raw SQL. NHibernate will
>   be able to populate entity instances
>   from the sql-query and return those as
>   the query result. See [**here**](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-creating) and [**here**](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries).